# Elasticsearch slow performance for huge data retrieval with source field

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to search from more than 10 million records, most records contains 1 to 25 words. I want to retrieve data from it, the method I'm using now is drastically slow for big data retrieval as I'm trying to get data from the source field. I want a method that can make this process faster. I'm free to use other database or anything with ElasticSearch. Can anyone suggest some good Ideas and Example for this?

I've tried searching for solution on google and one solution I found was pagination and I've already applied it wherever it's possible but pagination is not an option when I want to retrieve many(5000+) hits in one query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of queries are you running? What is your topology? Are you using cluster mode ?

Comment: You can profile your searches with: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**scroll**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)

> While a search request returns a single “page” of results, the scroll
>   API can be used to retrieve large numbers of results (or even all
>   results) from a single search request, in much the same way as you
>   would use a cursor on a traditional database.

Comment: In pagination mode, I'm using that only. But I want to retrieve whole result at once now. I've also tried looping with scroll but that's slow too.

Comment: I don't understand, are you using pagination mode or scroll? As you can read scroll can be used the retrieve `event all results`

Comment: I've done pagination using scroll. And now I want to retrieve all data at once. No pagination, No Scroll cause I want to process that data into my application and show it to client. Use of source field to retrieve data is making it slow as per my knowledge.

Comment: Oh, well, that is not what search engines like ElasticSearch were designed for. Can you describe your use case ?